# Let $X$ be a continuous r.v. with PDF $f$. Then $X$ is symmetric about $\mu$ if and only if $f(x) = f (2\mu − x)$ for all $x$.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I encountered the following proposition:

> Let $X$ be a continuous r.v. with PDF $f$. Then $X$ is symmetric (in terms of the PDF) about $\mu$ if and only if $f(x) = f (2\mu − x)$ for all $x$.
>
> Note:
>
> $$f(x) = f(2\mu - x) \ \text{for all} \ x$$
>
> is equivalent to
>
> $$f(\mu - x) = f(\mu + x) \ \text{for all} \ x$$

I'm struggling to see how any of this is intuitively reasonable.

Why would $f(x) = f (2\mu − x)$ for all $x$ mean that $X$ is symmetric?

And how is $f(x) = f(2\mu - x) \ \text{for all} \ x$ equivalent to $f(\mu - x) = f(\mu + x) \ \text{for all} \ x$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: What does "$X$ is symmetric mean"? Does it mean that its pdf is symmetric around $\mu$? If that is the case, there is nothing to prove here, given that $f_X(\mu+x)=f_X(\mu-x)$ for all $x$, which is what symmetric means.

Comment: @GReyes I have made an edit to clarify. It means symmetric in terms of the PDF.

Comment: @GReyes That part makes sense to me, but how is it equivalent to $f(x) = f(2\mu - x) \ \text{for all} \ x$? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Ok then. The fact that $f(x) = f(2\mu - x)$ for all $x$ equivalent to $f(\mu - x) = f(\mu + x) $ for all $x$ follows by replacing $x$ in the first relation by $\mu-y$ and then $2\mu-x=\mu+y$. Since $y$ is as arbitrary as $x$, you are done.

Comment: @GReyes Ahh, I see. I think the confusion is due to notational abuse. In both cases, $x$ is a bound variable (as opposed to a free variable), is it not? If so, then to use it twice in this way doesn't make sense, and another variable should be used, as you did.

Comment: I would say that $x$ is free in both cases, but to transition from one form to the other it would not be wise to replace $x$ by $\mu-x$. The second form is just a "symmetrized" version of the first.

Comment: @GReyes Ok, thank you again for the clarification.